Permanently disable Android adaptive notifications on REVVL 5G
I have a T-Mobile REVVL 5G. I want adaptive notifications set to NONE permanently.
Adaptive notifications continuously block a much-needed application despite all settings to enable its notifications (no battery optimization, run app in background, unlimited data). Literally every notification setting in the application and the system are enabled to permit the notifications, but as soon as adaptive notifications switch back on, I stop receiving them.
Is there any way to prevent Android from reenabling them?

Also posted on Google Support: https://support.google.com/android/thread/288214849/permanently-disable-android-adaptive-notifications

A quick search revealed that it's a common occurrence that this setting gets reset randomly, including a similar question on here: Adaptive Notifications re-enabling itself after some updates (answered with a workaround for a different-but-related issue)
